# Once ssh-agent is killed due to power cycle, why am I still allowed to ssh without a password?

Tags: bash, openssh, rhel-6

I have two linux servers running RHEL.

I set up private keys for `ssh` using `ssh-keygen`. I also copied the `.ssh` folder from the user I created to that same user with intentions of using `openmpi`. I then started `ssh-agent` from the bash shell and used `ssh-add` to add private identities.

I then proceeded to `ssh` from one server to the other with hope of password-less `ssh`. It worked!

Upon reboot, the `ssh-agent` process is killed and `ssh-add -l` reports no identities/keys are stored. I expect this.

But why am I still able to `ssh` from one to the other without a password? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your private key passphrase protected?

Comment: How can I check? Is this just referring to it's file permissions?

Comment: When you did ssh-keygen, you will have been prompted for a password, if you don't enter one, then you can use the private key without ssh-agent, but it is less secure.

Comment: Yes I entered a pass-phrase and and also had to enter it again when adding the key to ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

If your identity is stored in default path (`~/.ssh/id_{rsa,dsa,ecdsa}`), then your client picks them up and uses them regardless they are added in the agent or not. If the keys are protected by passphrase, then it asks for it, if not it just uses them. It is feature.

Comment: I left that out as a key part of my question sorry, but I do have a pass-phrase set up. I enter the pass-phrase once and then add it to the ssh-agent in hopes of it storing the key for me.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: post verbose log from your connection `ssh -vvv host`. It should be clear from that what is going on.

Comment: My question is once, ssh-agent is killed and no key is stored, shouldn't I have to use ssh-add again?

Comment: Yes, you should, or better you should set up `ssh-agent` starting during startup. Or gnome-keyring.

Comment: Ya and it doesn't prompt me for password when nothing is stored in ssh-agent, I want to know why.

Comment: As I already wrote in the third comment, post the log. Without it I can't say. Also you might have different keys without passphrase copied-over or many possibilities.